# Why do I get these errors in my module?

Tags: forms

I am trying to use the Date module in a module I am writing, but I get the following errors:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for myform_data_entry_form() in myform_data_entry_form() (line 28 of D:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\myform\myform.module).
>   Warning: Missing argument 2 for myform_data_entry_form() in myform_data_entry_form() (line 28 of D:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\modules\myform\myform.module).

This is the code I am using in my module.

```
function myform_help($path, $arg) {
switch ($path) {
      case "admin/help#myform":
        return '<p>'.  t("Displays links to nodes created on this date") .'</p>';
        break;
    } 
 }

function myform_menu() {
  $items['myform/data_entry_form'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'myform_data_entry_form' 
  );
  return $items;
}


function myform_permission(){
  return array(
    'access myform content' => array(
      'title' => t('Access content for the myform module')
    ) 
  );
}

function myform_data_entry_form($form,&$form_submit) {
  $form['curdate'] = array('#type' => 'date_popup', '#title' => 'Date', '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y');

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drupal forms should be called using the `drupal_get_form()` method, even from menu callbacks. Your menu item needs to look like this:

```
$items['myform/data_entry_form'] = array(
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('myform_data_entry_form') 
);

return $items;
```

Make sure you clear Drupal's caches each time you make a change in `hook_menu()`, otherwise it won't get picked up.